# Get 'java.sql.Timestamp' object has no attribute 'weekday' error in Nifi ExecuteScript processor

Tags: python, apache-nifi

Codes in my python script:

```
import datetime

flowFile = session.get()
if flowFile is not None:
   fltDt = flowFile.getAttribute('FLT_DT')
   dateObj = datetime.datetime.strptime(fltDt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
   weekday = dateObj.weekday() + 1

   attrMap = {}
   attrMap['WEEKDAY'] = weekday

   for key, value in attrMap.iteritems():
       flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, key, str(value))

   session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

This simple piece of code runs well with python interpreter as well as in Jython shell. However, when running from Nifi ExecuteScript processor, it always reports error:

```
2017-07-16 08:17:34,417 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-9] o.a.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript ExecuteScript[id=015d1000-4a59-1cf3-2aec-c963c03e3d8b] Failed to process session due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: AttributeError: 'java.sql.Timestamp' object has no attribute 'weekday' in <script> at line number 18: {}
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: AttributeError: 'java.sql.Timestamp' object has no attribute 'weekday' in <script> at line number 18
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript.onTrigger(ExecuteScript.java:230)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1120)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:147)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:132)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: AttributeError: 'java.sql.Timestamp' object has no attribute 'weekday' in <script> at line number 18
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.scriptException(PyScriptEngine.java:202)
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:42)
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:31)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at org.apache.nifi.script.impl.JythonScriptEngineConfigurator.eval(JythonScriptEngineConfigurator.java:59)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript.onTrigger(ExecuteScript.java:220)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.python.core.PyException: null
    at org.python.core.Py.AttributeError(Py.java:205)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.noAttributeError(PyObject.java:1013)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__getattr__(PyObject.java:1008)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx1359.f$0(<script>:31)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx1359.call_function(<script>)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:167)
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
    at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1386)
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.eval(__builtin__.java:497)
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.eval(__builtin__.java:501)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.eval(PythonInterpreter.java:259)
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:40)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Can anyone help? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the call to `datetime.strptime()` returns a java.sql.Timestamp object rather than a Python datetime.  I found a [reference to similar Jython behavior](https://groups.google.com/a/streamsets.com/forum/#!topic/sdc-user/Sisg5dHUNBI), but not a concrete explanation for why this is.

As a workaround, you might use [`getDay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay--) from the java.util.Date parent class instead.  It's not quite an exact substitute.  In Python, [`weekday()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) returns Monday as 0, where Java's [`getDay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay--) returns Sunday as 0.

```
dateObj = datetime.datetime.strptime(fltDt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
weekday = dateObj.getDay()
```

Comment: Thanks James! I'll give it a try. However, I use javascript instead for the time being ;)